# Jmeter HTTP Request send multiple xml payloads

Tags: xml, httprequest, jmeter

Is there anyone who was using Jmeter to send multiple HTTP Requests with different bodies?
I need to send 500 HTTP Request using different XML payloads to the API.

I can create 500 HTTP Request samplers and for each of them use different xml payload, but i think there should be better solution doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter provides several ways on requests parametrization.

The most straightforward way is having 500 files with payloads like

```
file1.xml
file2.xml
...
file500.xml
```

And use [Counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) and [Loop Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) combination

Another option is using [__FileToString](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) and [__threadNum](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) functions combination.

See [How to Use JMeter Functions](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) post series for details on how it can be done.

Third option is load all 500 files into JMeter Variables and iterate through them in [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm going to try using solutions you provided.